# Error bar sizing skewed when using plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a chart which has an error bar on it:

[image]

However, when I put the chart inside a plotly wrapper, the error bar sizing gets messed up, as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for keeping the error bar width the same size as the bar, as shown in plot 1, but while keeping the plot rendering with plotly?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(peeps= c("Bill", "Bob", "Becky"),
                  vals = c(10, 15, 12),
                  goals = c(8, 13, 10), 
                  grp = c("Bears", "Bears", "Mongoose") %>% as.factor)
p1 <- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = peeps, y = vals, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(data = dat,
                aes(ymin = goals, ymax = goals),
                                    color = "blue",
                size = 1,
                linetype = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip()

p1

ggplotly(p1) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h",
                       xanchor = "center",
                       y = -0.15,
                       x = 0.5))
```

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but for this one plot, adding `width = 3.125` to `geom_errorbar` will generate a plotly graph that resembles the ggplot above (but this width looks silly on the ggplot graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `geom_segment()` instead of `geom_errorbar()` is a work-around for this problem.

```
dat <- data.frame(peeps= c("Bill", "Bob", "Becky") %>% as.factor,
                  vals = c(10, 15, 12),
                  goals = c(8, 13, 10), 
                  grp = c("Bears", "Bears", "Mongoose"),
                  rowid = 1:3)
  
p1 <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = peeps, y = vals, fill = grp, order = rowid)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = as.numeric(peeps)-0.45,
    xend = as.numeric(peeps)+0.45,
    y = goals, yend = goals),
    color = "blue",
    size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(p1) %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h",
                       xanchor = "center",
                       y = -0.15,
                       x = 0.5))
```

[image: bars with bars]

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you so much. Making me and hopefully my boss happy :D

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck!